# Clicking a bar in the reputation graph gives "An error occurred when loading rep info"

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, reputation-graph

I'm seeing

> An error occurred when loading rep info

when I click on a bar in my reputation graph, and the details are not displayed. This is occurring on all sites, so I'd be hesitant to say it's related to the rep changes being tested here on Meta. Screenshot from Android:

[image: herp]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already fixed, it'll go out in just a moment.

Comment: So fast I can't even accept the answer yet.  Thanks!

Comment: It looks like [the error is coming again](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf4bT.png). I tried it on different user's profile. I found this question while asking the same question. So reporting here.

Comment: @hims056: Reproduced in chrome.

Comment: It's been re-fixed and the change is going out in just a moment

Comment: @Sklivvz Well get on over to [that other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194248/collapsible-fieldsets-error-for-previous-dates) and collect your useless meta points!

Comment: This error is still occurring for me on my Stack Overflow account. I have noticed that it is still out for a couple other Stack Exchange websites as well. I am using Chrome, if that helps.