# Collapsible fieldsets error for previous dates

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, reputation-history

The best way to determine the error is to try it yourself. In the reputation page I clicked(try to expand) the arrow (collapsible fieldset) in a certain day and pawn an error like this:

[image]

```
Error occurred when loading post body.
```

I tested it on Chrome and Firefox.

**Update:**

I also tested it on the following sites:

1. Anime & Manga
2. Stackoverflow
3. Meta Stackoverflow
4. Arqade
5. Photography
6. Superuser
7. DBA
8. Server Fault

Now, I assume that this happens to all stack network to all browsers though I haven't tested on mobile/tablet device yet.

Comment: Repro with IE 10.0.9200.16484 on Win RT on MSO and SO.

Comment: Repro on mac chrome (29.0.1547.55) on the dates that are already collapsed. If it is an expanded date, then I can collapse and reopen with no error. Also am seeing the error on DBA.SE

Comment: Yes, but I am referring to previous dates. Not the opened dates.

Comment: It is also applicable on the [graphical UI](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NmFjy.png) as well.

Comment: You just wait...some dev is gonna come by and say they were "backfilling some repository", but it's all fixed now.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question today. I found [the similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123869/187824) with status-completed tag. So [I asked Nick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123869/clicking-a-bar-in-the-reputation-graph-gives-an-error-occurred-when-loading-rep/123872#comment-610397) to re-view the bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's fixed and will be out soon.